# When would it be a good idea to implement data structures rather than using built-in ones?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

What is the purpose of creating your own linked list, or other data structure like maps, queues or hash function, for some programming language, instead of using built-in ones, or why should I create it myself? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! There are several reasons why you might want to do this.

For starters, not all programming languages ship with all the nice data structures that you might want to use. For example, C doesn't have built-in libraries for *any* data structures (though it does have `bsearch` and `qsort` for arrays), so if you want to use a linked list, hash table, etc. in C you need to either build it yourself or use a custom third-party library.

Other languages (say, JavaScript) have built-in support for some but not all types of data structures. There's no native JavaScript support for linked lists or binary search trees, for example. And I'm not aware of *any* mainstream programming language that has a built-in library for [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), though please let me know if that's not the case!

The above examples indicate places where a lack of support, period, for some data structure would require you to write your own. But there are other reasons why you might want to implement your own custom data structures.

A big one is efficiency. Put yourself in the position of someone who has to implement a dynamic array, hash table, and binary search tree for a particular programming language. You can't possibly know what workflows people are going to subject your data structures to. Are they going to do a ton of inserts and deletes, or are they mostly going to be querying things? For example, if you're writing a binary search tree type where insertions and deletions are common, you probably would want to look at something like a red/black tree, but if insertions and deletions are rare then an AVL tree would work a lot better. But you can't know this up front, because you have to write one implementation that stands the test of time and works pretty well for all applications. That might counsel you to pick a "reasonable" choice that works well in many applications, but isn't aggressively performance-tuned for your specific application. Coding up a custom data structure, therefore, might let you take advantage of the particular structure of the problem you're solving.

In some cases, the language specification makes it impossible or difficult to use fast implementations of data structures as the language standard. For example, C++ requires its associative containers to allow for deletions and insertions of elements without breaking any iterators into them. This makes it significantly more challenging / inefficient to implement those containers with types like B-trees that might actually perform a bit better than regular binary search trees due to the effects of caches. Similarly, the implementation of the unordered containers has an interface that assumes chained hashing, which isn't necessarily how you'd want to implement a hash table. That's why, for example, there's Google's [alternatives to the standard containers](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/container) that are optimized to use custom data structures that don't easily fit into the language framework.

Another reason why libraries might not provide the fastest containers would be challenges in providing a simple interface. For example, [cuckoo hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing) is a somewhat recent hashing scheme that has excellent performance in practice and guarantees worst-case efficient lookups. But to make cuckoo hashing work, you need the ability to select *multiple* hash functions for a given data type. Most programming languages have a concept that each data type has "a" hash function (`std::hash<T>`, `Object.hashCode`, `__hash__`, etc.), which isn't compatible with this idea. The languages could in principle require users to write families of hash functions with the idea that there would be many different hashes to pick from per object, but that complicates the logistics of writing your own custom types. Leaving it up to the programmer to write families of hash functions for types that need it then lets the language stay simple.

And finally, there's just plain innovation in the space. New data structures get invented all the time, and languages are often slow to grow and change. There's been a bunch of research into new faster binary search trees recently (check out [WAVL trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAVL_tree) as an example) or new hashing strategies (cuckoo hashing and the "Swiss Table" that Google developed), and language designers and implementers aren't always able to keep pace with them.

So, overall, the answer is a mix of "because you can't assume your favorite data structure will be there" and "because you might be able to get better performance rolling your own implementations."

There's one last reason I can think of, and that's "to learn how the language and the data structure work." Sometimes it's worthwhile building out custom data types just to sharpen your skills, and you'll often find some really clever techniques in data structures when you do!

All of this being said, I wouldn't recommend defaulting to coding your own version of a data structure every time you need one. Library versions are usually a pretty safe bet unless you're looking for extra performance or you're missing some features that you need. But hopefully this gives you a better sense as to why you may want to consider setting aside the default, well-tested tools and building out your own.

Hope this helps!